# is jsonwebtoken and signing/verifying/decoding completly synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I have some concerns regarding jsonwebtoken and signing/verifying/decoding mechanism.

In docs there are both Asynchronous and Synchronous versions.

> (Asynchronous) If a callback is supplied, function acts
> asynchronously.  The callback is called with the decoded payload if
> the signature is valid and optional expiration, audience, or issuer
> are valid. If not, it will be called with the error.
>
> (Synchronous) If a callback is not supplied, function acts
> synchronously. Returns the payload decoded if the signature is valid
> and optional expiration, audience, or issuer are valid. If not, it
> will throw the error.

I assumed that there must be some  benefit for using the asynchronous version but it seems that everything that occurs during signing/verifying/decoding is completely synchronous as pointed out in https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/111

So, can i safely do for example

```
async function (req,res,next){
...
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret); 
const user = await User.findById(decoded.id) 
...
}
```

and be 100% sure that it will not block the main thread assuming thousands of simultaneous requests ?
I have read a lot of articles about this, but no one is explicitly saying this.

Comment: It will block the main thread, regardless of which version you use. Because the mechanism of verifying is synchronous. And using async version doesn't change that, only postpones the execution. That being said, this operation is very fast, and you should not worry about it. In fact sync version will be faster (because it doesn't involve Promise allocation). The fact that a function acts either as synchronous or asynchronous is a horrible design. Also there's no benefit in wrapping purely sync operation into an async one. I really don't understand the design choices here.

Comment: Ok i understand, so the async version is just postponing this synchronous operation and have no real effect on performance. Thanks for clarification.